# Finding output values of point density calculation?

Tags: arcmap, point, density

I ran the point density tool and got an output, but because the 'Area Units' option in the Point Density was locked to Square_Map_Units - I don't know how to tell what units the density was calculated with, and no way to convert that into density/km2 which is my desired output.

Comment: the (area units) should be adjustable when you select your point shapefile.

Comment: Moh, the (Area units) option remains greyed out through the whole of entering information into the tool. I tried creating a new arcmap document and re-added my layers and it is still greyed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the tool ([Point Density](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/point-density.htm)) that:

> If the output units is anything other than feet or meters, the output
>   area density units will be set to SQUARE_MAP_UNITS. That is, the
>   output density units will be the square of the linear units of the
>   output spatial reference.

For example,

> if the output linear units is
>   centimeters, the output area density units will be SQUARE_MAP_UNITS,
>   which would result in square centimeters. If the output linear units
>   is kilometers, the output area density units will be SQUARE_MAP_UNITS,
>   which would result in square kilometers.

Comment: Thank you Moh, between this and your other answer I was able to find out what the issue was. I needed to change my data to a projected coordinate system (using the project Data Management tool). I thought I had done that already, but I did it for my Data Frame, not my actual Data. Thanks for the help!